# Contour lines of constant absolute value/phase of $z\mapsto\exp(-z^2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, complex-numbers, error-function

In the following problem I am going to use terms (denoted with quotation marks) I couldn't properly translate - if you happen to know the particular terms please feel free to edit them. Hopefully you will, using my solution, understand what am I referring to. Moreover this is a preparation for a larger problem about the error function.

> Sketch the "lines of constant absolute value and lines of constant phase" of $\mathbb C\ni z\mapsto \exp(-z^2)$.

Let $z=a+\mathrm ib$ be our complex number then

$$\exp(-(a+\mathrm ib)^2) = \exp(-a^2-2\mathrm iab+b^2) = \exp(-a^2+b^2)\exp(-2\mathrm iab)=R\exp(\mathrm i\varphi).$$

In the first case we are interested in all complex numbers $z=a+\mathrm ib$ which have the same constant absolute value $|\exp(-z^2)|=\exp(-a^2+b^2)=R$. It is fairly obvious that two possible lines are described by $a=b$ and $a=-b$. There are definitely more of those lines but I had no good idea how to find them hence I did ask WolframAlpha which yields

[image: contour plot for constant absolute value]

Is there any approach to find some of those lines other that just trial-and-error by letting $a$ be some specific value and trying out to find suitable $b$ s.t. $\exp(-a^2+b^2)$ is constant?

---

Similiarly one can argue about the constant phase $\operatorname{Arg}(\exp(-z^2))=-2ab = \varphi$ which is very similiar to above with $a=0,b$ arbitrary and the other way round as two trivial solutions. The others apparently being the following ones

[image: contour plot for constant phase]

Once again: how may I properly find those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, note that:
$$\exp(-a^2+b^2)=R \Rightarrow b = \pm \sqrt{a^2 + \ln(R)}.$$
For each value of $R>0$, you get two functions of $b$ in terms of $a$. In particular, $R=1$ gives you the straight lines you mentioned above.

Recarding the second case, you can proceed analogously:
$$-2ab = \varphi \Rightarrow b=-\frac{\varphi}{2a}.$$
With $\varphi>0$ you obtain the curves on the first and third quadrants; $\varphi=0$ gives you the straight lines and $\varphi<0$, the curves on the second and fourth quadrants.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$
R=e^{b^2-a^2}=k \quad \Rightarrow \quad b^2-a^2=\ln k
$$
and
$$
\varphi=-2ab=h\quad \Rightarrow \quad ab=-\frac{h}{2}
$$

do you recognize the equations of two families of hyperbolas?